# Collapse a table's column with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a table with entire columns I'd like to hide from view.

The real-life scenario is mobile platforms. I desire a table's less useful information to be hidden so that it fits on a narrow screen.

I've played around with it but there doesn't seem to be a true way to get this to happen.
http://jsfiddle.net/3712Ledn/

Even if I apply the class to all cells of the same column and then apply `hidden` or `collapse`, they still take up space.

If I turn `display: none;`, then the columns *do* collapse, but `auto` width columns do not expand to take up the new space.

Is there any way to achieve this without using JS?

Comment: you fiddle needs the correct url?

Comment: @Aaron http://jsfiddle.net/3712Ledn/ -- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps if i understand you. The seconds column is hidden and the first column stretches over the full page.
http://jsfiddle.net/uow30orv/

```
<table id="real" width="100%">...
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a tag inside the cell you want to collapse, then use a `table-layout: fixed;` on your `<table>`, this way, you will be able to set a `width: 0;` to the column you want to hide.